# Bulk Inserts Failing with SQL Server Merge Replication Identity Range Management

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, merge-replication

We have an issue with merge replication where we have a background process inserting rows in bulk.  These inserts sometimes fail with the message that

> The insert failed. It conflicted with an identity range check
>   constraint in database ‘′, replicated table ‘’, column ‘′. If the
>   identity column is automatically managed by replication, update the
>   range as follows: for the Publisher, execute
>   sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange; for the Subscriber, run the
>   Distribution Agent or the Merge Agent.

I've done a lot of reading and tinkering with inserts of different sizes and various settings for the Publisher Range Size, Subscriber Range Size, and Range Threshold Percentage.  If I set the bulk insert size to something not divisible by 10 and repeatedly insert rows, I cannot find settings that are immune to the insert error.  Even if I set Range Threshold Percentage to 50 or 1 it still doesn't allow me to insert batches that are close to 1/3rd the size of the Subscriber Range Size.  Should there not be some setting like 1000 rows for the subscriber range and 50% threshold that if I insert 317 rows(prime number) repeatedly it doesn't error?  If I were to say, I'm not going to insert more than 5000 rows at a time, does anyone have a recommendation for what to use for the settings that would never result in the insert error?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your existing threshold is and exactly how many rows you are inserting, all i can tell you is that your subscriber range is probably too small.

I also want to ensure you have a clear understanding of what @threshold parameter does.  If your range size is 1000, and @threshold = 60, then it will allocate a new range at 600.

So, if you have a max of 5000 rows to be bulk inserted, and your standard range for user/merge insert operations is 1000, with a threshold of 80, you would want your range to be 7500:

```
(5000 + 1000) / .80 = 7500
```

This way if you were on the cusp of hitting the end of the user range (say at 999), you could do the 5000 bulk inserts without triggering a new range allocation.

Comment: This is good in theory only.  Say I set up your scenario.(Subscriber range of 7500, threshold 80)  It works when I insert 5000 rows repeatedly on the publisher, but it's not what you'd expect.  Every third insert of 5000 assigns two new ranges of identities.  Also, if I try to repeatedly insert 4999 rows, it will fail on the 4th insertion of 4999 rows.  I can do this repeatedly.  I run sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange, then insert 4999, insert 4999, insert 4999, insert 4999(fails), repeat.  This behavior is exactly the same with threshold = 80, threshold = 1, threshold = 10.

Comment: I guess threshold isn't actually doing anything per MS documentation(taken from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151736%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

This value must be specified, but it is only used by: Subscribers using queued updating subscriptions; and Subscribers to merge publications running SQL Server Compact or previous versions of other SQL Server editions. For more information, see the "Assigning Identity Ranges" section of Replicate Identity Columns.